# ¿Está bien escribir en "Spanglish"?

Tags: discusión, idiomas

¿Es extrictamente necesario escribir todas las preguntas y respuestas en `español`, o podemos usar algunas palabras en `inglés`?

Ejemplo:

- Spanglish:

> Actualmente hay un bug en la alineación de los elementos de la lista de preguntas debido a la longitud de palabras palabras en singular vs plural.

- Español:

> Actualmente hay un defecto en la alineación de los elementos de la lista de preguntas debido a la diferencia de longitud entre las palabras en plural y singular.

---

Yo estoy de acuerdo en que escribamos en **`(e)spanglish`**; sin embargo, eso no motivaría un cambio en el nombre de la comunidad a **"Stack Overflow en Espanglish"**?

Nota: Omitir cualquier error ortográfico o gramatical involuntario.

Comment: Recién le dí un vistazo a [espanglish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espanglish). Me pareció muy interesante entre otras cosas porque distingue entre "spanglish" y el uso de anglisismos. Otro término interesante es el de [jerga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerga), en espcífico el apartado sobre jerga profesional.

Answer (score 36):

Creo que hay palabras generalmente aceptadas y conocidas entre los programadores de habla hispana (y otros idiomas) que si las traducimos de forma forzada al español se verían mal. Algunas están incluso aceptadas por la RAE.

Traducirlas podría dificultar las búsquedas e ir en contra de la misión principal que es facilitar la información a las personas de habla hispana.

Hay muchísimas palabras que los programadores nos topamos en inglés e, incluso si no sabemos el idioma, sabemos escribirlas aunque quizá no pronunciarlas debidamente. Esto debido a que estamos frente a una computadora todo el día y casi todo está pensado en inglés.

Un ejemplo de que sea contraproducente traducir al español, aparte del que propusiste en la pregunta:

- ¿Dónde encuentro mi archivo de **anfitriones** en Windows?
- ¿Dónde encuentro mi archivo de **hosts** en Windows?

Otro ejemplo:

- ¿Cómo hacer correctamente un **pull request**?
- (No se me ocurre una traducción ni medianamente aceptable)

Yo creería que si la palabra puede ser traducida sin que el sentido común te diga que está fuera de lugar, entonces se podrían poner ambas.

Por ejemplo:

- ¿Cuánto tiempo tarda en pasar el `recolector de basura` *(garbage collector)* en Java?

Comment: pull request = "¿petición de estirar?" Definitivamente, mejor no traducir algunas cosas. :-)

Comment: @Konamiman Más que _estirar_ sería _traer, jalar_. Sigue siendo mejor dejarla as is. Ehmm.. Digo... _Como está_ :)

Comment: @Konamiman, sino me equivoco, la traducción correcta para _pull request_ es "Solicitar extracción".

Comment: @drielnox ...con lo cual parece que estás pidiendo cita con el dentista. X-D

Comment: "pull request" = "solicitud de jalada" // Me parece legítimo... xD

Comment: @JorgeArtware si alguien de mi equipo plantea "solicitud de jalada" todos entendemos que vamos a salir a tomar unos aguardientes... lo dejo en "pull request"

Comment: ¿Ya leyeron todos? dice @quevedo que él paga las chelas, salud.

Comment: @JorgeArtware Tocará invitar Corona Beer, ya que está de moda. Si coincidimos geográficamente, en algún momento, será un placer compartir unos "guaros".

Answer (score 8):

Soy un participante StackOverflow en portugués. Así que por favor perdona mis posibles errores gramaticales en esta respuesta.

En SOpt, usuarios en general, suelen escribir como mejor les parezca, cada uno de acuerdo a sus preferencias.
En la práctica, esto no genera ningún problema real y casi todos los usuarios se comportan bien en este sentido.
Tenemos varios tipos de problemas allí que surgen debido a la gran cantidad de usuarios, pero seguro como el uso de algunos términos en Inglés definitivamente no es y nunca ha sido uno de nuestros problemas.

La mayor parte de los problemas que tenemos en preguntas y respuestas viene de graves problemas de formato, puntuacion, gramática y ortografía del texto en portugués. Nunca he visto un caso en que el abuso de los términos en Inglés era el problema.

Por lo tanto, hoy en día no hay mucha razón para ir imponiendo normas para obligar a todos los términos a traducir o no, e incluso si lo hiciera, tratar de imponer este tipo de cosas no es productivo.
Tratando de inventar políticas de este es perder el tiempo tratando de resolver un problema que probablemente nunca tendría.
Por otra parte, al final pocas personas realmente se preocupan si alguien ha escrito "bug" en lugar de "defecto", porque hay muchos términos que se traduce tan difícil, inusual, ambiguo, inexacto, poco clara o sonidos extraños.

Así que lo que propongo es dejar este tema de lado. A menos que alguien muestra que hay una fuerte evidencia en contrario, esto no es un problema real.

Comment: Você aqui! Queria aprender espanhol para usar esse site. Mas fico feliz em ter ajudado a dar um commit.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Então somos dois. Também gostaria de aprender espanhol. :)

Comment: ¿Cómo así, "também gostaria de aprender"? ¡La redacción del texto parece perfecta! Sólo veo una expresión portuguesa que tiene palabra específica en español: "tienden a escribir" => "suelen escribir"; y algo que no entiendo a que te refieres: "muchos términos que se traduce tan difícil [...]", creo que falta un adverbio o algo...

Comment: @brasofilo. Eu sou um cheater - Quem "redigiu" isso foi o tradutor do Google, eu escrevi em português e ele me respondeu em espanhol ;) - "muchos términos" é (ou deveria ser) "muitos termos".

Comment: Bienvenido, Victor. Tu español fica— digo queda— muy bien. :)  Yo en este caso diría *para **ir** imponiendo* y no *estar*, pero no me preguntes el porqué. Y tienes razón en lo que has escrito.

Answer (score 7):

**Adaptémonos al uso real de los términos**

Este sitio no se trata tanto de ser puristas del idioma como de tener una comunidad de programadores en español.  Dado que el mundo de la informática está ampliamente dominado por el inglés, resulta *muy* extraño en ocasiones traducir un término si este se usa *siempre* en inglés.  Por ejemplo, en mi día a día "bug" y "pull request" son términos perfectamente comunes, que cualquiera entiende y no necesitan traducción.

Un problema importante a este respecto es la discrepancia de términos entre los diferentes dialectos del español, principalmente entre el español de España y el español de América (y estoy seguro de que dentro de América también habrá discrepancias, aunque no las conozco).  Por ejemplo, en buena parte de América es común hablar de un *array* como un *arreglo*, mientras que en España simplemente decimos *array* (y más de uno se preguntará qué narices es un arreglo si no se le ha expuesto previamente al término).  De igual manera, términos traducidos en diferentes dialectos pueden resultar en diferentes términos, como el ejemplo de *template* por *molde* que menciona [Dyzann en su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/87/105)

Por norma general estas son las reglas por las que me suelo guiar yo personalmente:

- No traducir términos que no se traducen en el día a día y que en general se entienden sin problemas o no tienen una traducción obvia.  Es el caso de  *bug*, *pull request* e incluso *commit*.
- Si se está hablando de código concreto, nunca traducir nombres o conceptos sin previamente mencionar a lo que se hace referencia.  Por ejemplo, si estamos hablando de la clase `Date` de Java, en lugar de simplemente hablar de *fechas*, deberíamos dejar claro que hablamos de *objetos de la clase `Date`, no de fechas en general*.
- Procurar, en la medida de lo posible, no usar términos específicos del dialecto concreto de cada uno al traducir términos (y, a ser posible, en general).  Esto resulta increíblemente difícil, lo sé, pero no cuesta nada fijarse en cómo hablan los demás dentro de este sitio para hacerse una idea.  Ante la duda, diccionario.

Answer (score 5):

A mi me parece que lo mejor es poner la palabra en los dos idiomas con la aclaración entre parentesis de la palabra original en ingles.

> defecto (bug)

Esto va a ser de gran beneficio para todos porque muchos programadores con experiencia van a estar mas acostumbrados a ver la palabra en ingles, pero puede haber equipos en ciertos paises que se manejan completamente en castellano y no van a estar acostumbrados a la palabra en ingles.

En el caso de la palabra **bug**, no creo que nadie tenga problemas, pero por ejemplo hoy vi una pregunta de `C++` en la que usaban la palabra **molde**, la verdad es que no estoy segura a que se refiere. Creo que a `template`, pero si uno trabaja siempre leyendo documentación en ingles ciertas palabras le va a costar entenderlas, porque ya las tenemos asimiladas en ingles.

Een el caso del que hablo si la persona hubiera puesto:

> molde (template)

Hubiera entendido mas rápido, porque primero tuve que releer para ver si estaba entendiendo bien la pregunta.

Y si consideramos que en diferentes países seguramente se usan diferentes palabras para lo mismo (por ejemplo **ordenador** en España y **computadora** en Argentina) va a ser de gran utilidad tener una palabra básica en la que todos coincidimos, aunque no sea en castellano.

Comment: Personalmente, prefiero la traducción `plantilla` para `template`; aunque prefiero usar la palabra en inglés.

Comment: @gian1200 - Si es verdad, `plantilla` es mas usada, pero con que aclaren `template` sería suficiente para mi.

Comment: Yo preferiría bug...

Comment: Ya que hablan de plantillas: ¿qué les parece la desafortunada traducción de theme?, Aunque es usual hablar de **tema** ¿Alguien puede explicar que tiene que ver *tema* (traducción de theme) con **tema**?

Answer (score 3):

El Inglés y sus derivaciones van a ser el menor de los problemas; un mínimo de exposición a esa lengua viene por defecto en nuestro oficio.

Las variantes desde Patagônia a Los Andes y Caribe, pasando por el Mar de Cortés hasta el estrecho de Gibraltar me parecen un desafío más grande. Aquí al lado mismo, [en la respuesta de Dzyann](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/77/est%C3%A1-bien-escribir-en-spanglish/87#87), acabo de enterarme que `molde` corresponde a `plantilla`, y que para mí es el `template` de toda la vida...

Answer (score -3):

Para los editores, sugiero poner las palabras en inglés que generalmente no tienen traducción, entre `acentos inversos`, y cuando sea posible un link al wiki con la etiqueta de dicho concepto.

Comment: Los acentos inversos son para código, salida de terminal, ... (en general, cosas que tradicionalmente se ven con una fuente monoespaciada). Es tradicional usar itálica (texto entre signos de subrayado, en _markdown_) para poner palabras de otros idiomas que no son conocidas por el lector. Las palabras de otros idiomas que son ampliamente reconocidas, ya han pasado a formar parte del idioma, y no necesitan ninguna distinción tipográfica.

Comment: Exacto ^^^ La norma editorial son itálicas para palabras en otro idioma. Y el acento inverso debe ser usado preferentemente para código y no para destacar palabras.

Answer (score -6):

**Debemos traducirlo todo.**

Este es un sitio en español.

Pero no a costa de disminuir la utilidad del sitio. Hay términos puntuales en que se debe preservar el nombre en otro idioma.

- Comandos. `mkfs.ext3` por ejemplo crea (MaKe) un sistema de archivos (File System) ext3. No tiene sentido traducirlo como `crsa.ext3`. Pero sí debemos utilizar el término sistema de archivos y no el término filesystem.
- `/etc/hosts` es un archivo de configuración de red. No tiene sentido traducirlo como `/etc/anfitriones` porque aunque nuestro sistema esté configurado en español el archivo se va a seguir llamando `/etc/hosts`.
- Código fuente. `if a==3 printf("A"); else abort();` no debe traducirse como `si a==3 imprimef("A"); si no abortar();` El compilador no va a aceptar eso. Los comentarios sin embargo sí deben ser en castellano. Los nombres de variables, clases, métodos y similares se deben respetar en inglés (o francés o lo que sea) si son parte de una interfaz pública, en caso contrario se resiente su interoperatividad, esta parte es evidente. Pero incluso en identificadores privados lo conveniente es mantener el que haya en el código original para facilitar la contribución de código cooperativa, por ejemplo en proyectos de código libre.

Debemos traducir incluso aquellos términos que no tienen traducción o son de difícil traducción. En este caso es recomendable incluir entre paréntesis el término original para evitar confusiones. Cuando el sitio progrese y tome fuerza acabarán adoptándose de forma natural convenciones a cerca de cual es la traducción apropiada para cada término en otro idioma.

Ejemplos :

- **Deadlock = interbloqueo**. No es necesario ponerlo entre paréntesis pues es una traducción comunmente aceptada, al menos en mi experiencia. Ej : *Una técnica para evitar interbloqueos es adquirir los semáforos siempre en el mismo orden.*
- **hosts = huéspedes**. Cuando hagamos referencia al archivo debemos incluir siempre el nombre del archivo tal cual. Pero si hablamos del concepto debemos referirnos al concepto de archivo de huéspedes, en este caso yo pondría siempre entre paréntesis el nombre del archivo. Ej : *Para bloquear un sitio edita el archivo de huéspedes (`/etc/hosts`) y...*
- **pull request = ¿petición de incorporación?**. Yo siempre he pensando en términos de pull request. Pero ya es hora de hablar bien en castellano. No tengo nada claro cual es la mejor traducción pero sí tengo claro que no llegaremos a ella sin intentarlo. Lo mejor es intentar traducirla ponendo entre paréntesis "pull request". En algún momento a alguien se le ocurrirá una buena traducción y esta acabará siendo generalmente aceptada. Llegará el día en que no sea necesario poner "pull request" entre paréntesis y aún así todo el mundo lo tendrá claro. Ej : *Haz una petición de incorporación (pull request) tras corregir el error.*

Comment: Hay casos y casos. Deadlock y filesystem se pueden traducir sin problemas. Para hosts y pull request, creo que traducir sería contraproducente.

Comment: Si pongo petición de incorporación sin más no me va a entender nadie, eso es malo. Si pongo petición de incorporación (pull request) me va a entender todo el mundo, con la ventaja de que a largo plazo tendremos un sitio más amistoso para los españoles que no conocen inglés.

Comment: -1 ¿Traducir todo en una profesión en la que la mayoría de los términos vienen del inglés y que al traducir al español podrían ser diferentes debido a variaciones del dialecto del que responde? Gracias pero no. Hay palabras de la jerga como lo menciona @Konamiman que al traducirlas harían más mal que bien. Eso sin tener en cuenta los posibles cambios que tenga la traducción debido a las variaciones de significado propias de cada región hispanoparlante.

Comment: Además, no está de más preparar al público español a adaptarse al inglés. Habrá una ocasión en que buscarás algo tan pero tan técnico o documentación de plugins , que no encontrarás recursos en español pero sí en inglés (Ya me ha pasado) ¿Te quedarás atascado solo porque no está en español? o.O

Comment: Estoy bastante de acuerdo con José Antonio. Me molesta que mucha gente use tantos términos ingleses cuando está hablando en español. No sólo me refiero a esta profesión. Por ejemplo, hay hispanoablantes que usan "running", cuando deberían usar "correr". Algo similar pasa cuando se habla de computación. Creo que casi siempre es bueno intentar traducir al español. Si a continuación se pone el término inglés entre paréntesis, como muchos han sugerido, creo que a nadie le puede molestar. El término "recolector de basura" no me suena nada raro, porque me lo enseñaron así.

Comment: Voy a reiterar algo que comente arriba para objetar. Se ha vuelto común usar **tema** como traducción de *theme* Y, fue mi caso: No podía entender qué diablos era un tema, porque no tenía nada que ver con **tema** hasta que tuve la suerte de leer documentación en inglés y ver de qué hablaban. **Hay traducciones que hacen daño.**