# Edición sugerida por tener una palabra en inglés, pero de uso habitual (array)

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas, idiomas

<sup>*Relacionada: [¿Está bien escribir en “spanglish”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/77/127>)</sup>

Recién hicieron una sugerencia de edición sobre una publicación mía, sólo para cambiar la palabra `array` por `arreglo`<sup>([ver](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11676))</sup>. No estaba de acuerdo, pero al ver [el historial de revisiones de ese usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2229/tulains-c%C3%B3rdova?tab=activity&sort=revisions), observé que tenía muchos casos similares que habían sido aceptados por la comunidad. Viendo esto, decidí mejorar la edición, buscando un término medio con ambas acepciones y consultar acá.

Estoy en desacuerdo porque:

1. No agrega contenido sustancial y no mejora la interpretación de la lectura ni lo hace más acertado.

   Sin embargo, no me interesa discutir esta parte de la revisión, sino el hecho de que la comunidad acepte cambiar el uso de palabras en inglés como *array*. Incluso puedo estar equivocado, y que no sea superfluo, pero quiero enfocar en los siguientes puntos.

2. Siempre uso *array* (de hecho el uso de *arreglo* me parece ridículo). Y esto seguramente está relacionado a diferentes usos en cada país. Pero no soy el único. En este momento, en SOes se usa:

   - Array en [1.005](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=array) publicaciones, con 2.510 resultados en [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=array+site:es.stackoverflow.com).
   - Arreglo en [357](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=arreglo) publicaciones, con 1.140 resultados en [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=arreglo+site:es.stackoverflow.com).

   Claramente, este cambio hubiese hecho que el post sea más difícil de encontrar.

   Todos sabemos que en programación hay y siempre habrá palabras en inglés que se usan comúnmente. No veo ningún motivo para cambiar esto acá. Y tampoco creo que la solución sea corregir las publicaciones para que usen ambos términos al mismo tiempo como en "`arreglo (array)`". La solución no puede ser traducir 1.000+ artículos.

3. Es el uso que le da el autor de la publicación.

   Son acepciones utilizadas en el día a día y la intención del autor es emplear esa forma. No es incorrecto ya que todos sabemos qué significa, y corregirlo en este punto creo que es erróneo.

Me interesa saber cuál es la opinión generalizada sobre esto.

- ¿Hubiese estado acertado si rechazaba la corrección?
- ¿Se deberían desmotivar las revisiones que hagan traducciones que no mejoren la calidad de la publicación más allá de una traducción de un término que todos entendemos en inglés?
- ¿Deberíamos hacer hincapié en que algunas palabras usadas normalmente en inglés, no deberían ser traducidas? O si son traducidas, ¿insistir en que también debería quedar su forma en inglés como en "`arreglo (array)`"?

Comment: Yo aun estoy esperando que alguien me enlace algún documento oficial que indique que "arreglo" significa "array", y no es una simple adaptación fonética del inglés ([arrrray]->[arrrreglo]) en vez de usar un termino correcto Español como vector o matriz.
Puede que la RAE no contemple muchos términos considerados correctos en latinoamericana, pero verlo en otro documento "oficial" o como mínimo "académico" me dejaría mas tranquilo.
Mientras tanto, personalmente nunca lo he escuchado en entornos académicos y creo que "arreglo" es incorrecto. Pido disculpas si mi opinión a ofendido a alguien.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con  Arnau Castellví. Lo más que *arreglo* se acerca a *array* es que en su segunda acepción lleva la palabra **orden**.                 2. m. Regla, orden, coordinación.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo en que hay que motivar las traducciones para mejorar la calidad del sitio de cara a visitantes de *habla hispana*.

Pero creo que hay ciertas palabras (en determinados contextos) que traducirlas genera más *conflicto* que *beneficio*.

En el caso de `array`, de tener que plantearme traducirla, sugeriría `matriz`, `vector` o `colección` entre otras, referencias que son usadas en mi zona o entorno (a pesar de que nos las utilizo nunca).

Y ahora se plantea otra cuestión:

De todas, ¿Cual es la correcta?

- [Wikipedia `array`](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Array&redirect=no)
- [Manual PHP `array`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

> He puesto estos enlaces como ejemplo de traducciones, Wikipedia por su reconocimiento y php por la relación directa con la pregunta que ha motivado este tema.

Esto nos lleva a pensar que dependiendo desde que lugar del mundo sea leído, que tipo de lector, en que zona del mundo, o a través de que medio ha aprendido los términos de determinados *lenguajes de programación*, se van a sugerir distintas traducciones... mientras que en este caso, `array` es nativo del lenguaje que se está tratando, por lo que no da, o no debería dar lugar a error de interpretación, siendo común para todos los idiomas y siendo su alcance mayor que cualquier traducción o interpretación de su traducción.

Por mi parte, en este caso concreto, y en *opinión personal* no veo ni lógica ni beneficio en su traducción.

Comment: No. Al menos en muchos países de América Latina matriz no es sinónimo de array, en la literatura en español siempre el concepto ha estado asociado a un array de dos dimensiones. Vector lo he leído como interpretación del tipo de dato abstracto de arreglo, mientras que colección no es muy común en esta zona.

Comment: @dwarandae gracias por el comentario. Toda información y de distintas zonas es interesante para conocer más acerca del tema. Sin duda, con toda lógica,  `array` es común en todas las zonas, el resto de términos como bien comentas, no. En la literatura Española, _Matriz_ tiene una asociación directa a `array` tal cual, sin definir si es _uni_ o _multidimensional_. Es otro ejemplo de lo que defino en el penúltimo párrafo.

Answer (score 7):

Yo adhiero a la idea de que usar alguna palabra castellana en lugar de "array"

> No agrega contenido sustancial y no mejora la interpretación de la lectura ni lo hace más acertado.

Y "arreglo", además, es incorrecta.

Es incorrecta porque no representa el significado de la palabra inglesa. Un "array", cuando se usa en un texto de matemática, se refiere a una matriz, y cuando está en un texto de computación (que toma su léxico principalmente de la matemática), es una sucesión ordenada de elementos. Ninguna de las dos cosas está representada por un "arreglo".

El diccionario de la RAE muestra los usos de [*arreglo*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3iEfcKG):

> 1. m. Acción y efecto de arreglar.
> 2. m. Regla, orden, coordinación.
> 3. m. Avenencia, conciliación.
> 4. m. Transformación de una obra musical para poder interpretarla con instrumentos o voces distintos a los originales.
> 5. m. coloq. amancebamiento.

Una expresión como

```
int a[10];
```

no quiere decir nada de eso.

La idea más cercana es la de una "matriz" matemática, aunque creo que ya es tarde para adoptarla. Otra forma que me gustaba era "formación", como en "una formación de dos en fondo", que es una expresión más antigua aunque menos precisa que la matemática "matriz".

Una formación "de a uno en fondo" es lo más parecido que se me ocurre a un array en C.

Creo que empezó a traducirse como "arreglo" como una forma de transliteración, sólo porque suenan más o menos parecidas, un error desamprensivo con la lengua.

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión no se debería desmotivar las traducciones y los términos en español (**siempre que su uso esté ampliamente extendido**) porque éste es un sitio en ese idioma; lo que se debe desmotivar son las ediciones sólo para traducir una palabra. Son innecesarias y no mejoran la pregunta en nada.

Si el único cambio realizado en una edición es sustituir `array` por `arreglo` rechazaría la edición por ser superflua. Otra cosa es si se hubiesen hecho cambios adicionales, e incluso entonces puede que hubiese hecho "Aceptar y Editar" (aunque puede que no, para evitar entrar en una guerra innecesaria de ediciones/*rollback*).

Para solucionar el problema que mencionas de la búsqueda, lo que he hecho alguna vez es utilizar el término inglés y poner entre paréntesis su traducción en español (o viceversa). Algo como esto:

> Los arreglos (*arrays*) son estructuras de datos que bla bla bla...

No sé cómo de efectivo será, pero creo que eso haría que la pregunta/respuesta apareciese en búsquedas tanto para arreglo como para array.

Comment: Estamos de acuerdo en que no deberían aceptarse ediciones superfluas, y en que a veces conviene mejorar la edición (aceptar y editar), no en la parte de traducir TODO. No conozco a ningún profesional que llame arreglos a los arrays... Supongamos un caso donde es una edición que agrega contenido y además cambia "array" por "arreglo". Claramente se debe aceptar (porque se gana más en la calidad del artículo al fin y al cabo). Igual, ¿no deberíamos comentarle al editor que hay palabras que conviene dejarlas así, sabiendo que pronto editará sin revisión? ¿Cuál es tu postura sobre eso?

Comment: Un **arreglo** no es un array. Un **arreglo** se le hace a una pieza musical. Un **arreglo** de cuentas te deja maltrecho. En el mundo matemático e informático un array es universal mientras que un **arreglo** no. Es más, no había visto **arreglo** en este contexto en mi vida hasta que he lleagado a SOe. Definitivamente **array** es mi palabra.

Comment: @APO69 Array puede ser universal ahora, pero no lo era tanto antes. Cuando empezaba a programar, arreglo/vector era la terminología usada en casi todos los libros de texto que encontraba. Puede que ahora ya no se use tanto, pero arreglo era un término bastante común, y cuando leías array te chirriaba porque sonaba raro.

Comment: El Sinclair ZX Spectrum es un ordenador de 8 bits basado en el microprocesador Zilog Z80A, fabricado por la compañía británica Sinclair Research y lanzado al mercado el 23 de abril de **1982**. Del manual Basic:      ***Arrays (the way the ZX Spectrum handles string arrays is slightly non-standard) DIM . . .*** que significa:   **Arrays (la forma en que el ZX Spectrum maneja los arrays de cadenas es un poco no estándar) DIM.**                **La palabra array lleva con nosotros mucho más tiempo de lo que se creen algunos**.

Comment: @APO69 No termino de comprender. ¿Me estás diciendo que como la palabra array aparecía en un manual **en inglés** de los años 80, la palabra arreglo **en español** es incorrecta? ¿O en la traducción del manual en español aparecía como array? (Lo cuál es posible). En los libros académicos de los 90 y principios de 2000 en España, la palabra arreglo era bastante común (aunque sonaba a español de Hispanoamérica) y también se usaban otros términos como vector o lista (no enlazada). Que no quiere decir que el  array no se usara entonces. Solo que se utilizaban varios para referirse a lo mismo.

Comment: No, pero tú has dicho que *puede ser universal ahora*... y simplemente he mostrado que no es de ahora sino que lleva desde los origenes de la programación. Personalmente he de decir que hasta hace un mes, nunca antes habia visto la palabra arreglo en este contexto.

Comment: Que array, una palabra inglesa, apareciera en un texto en inglés no implica universalidad. Es normal, porque es el idioma. Cada idioma trata de adaptarse y acoger los nuevos términos como puede (p.e. balompié era normal antes, y ahora es fútbol, que no football). Ese es el caso de array.

Answer (score 2):

En Spanish.SE se estuvo debatiendo al respecto en:

- [¿Es realmente “arreglo” una mala traducción (por semejanza) de “array”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29069/1674)
- [¿Cuál es la traducción al español correcta del término “array”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29066/1674), donde PaperBirdMaster importó y añadió información de [una pregunta equivalente en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/234718/83).

Recomiendo la lectura de ambas preguntas y sus jugosas respuestas. Para sintetizar lo dicho, en la primera se defiende que *arreglo* es una mala traducción de *array*, pues el verbo *arreglar* no hace referencia a lo mismo que representa el concepto *array* en inglés, sino más bien a ordenar, coordinar, corregir.

En la segunda se ofrecen una serie de opciones que va de *arreglo* a *colección*, *formación*, *matriz* o *vector*, de mayor a menor encaje.

Por mi parte, debo reconocer que la palabra que menos equívocos me produce es la inglesa *array*, si bien acogería con los brazos abiertos alguna opción más nuestra. Sé que esto no es un grupo de presión ni nada, pero sí está en nuestras manos remar en alguna dirección concreta para popularizar términos, ya sea utilizándolos en nuestras publicaciones, ya sea sugiriendo sinónimos de etiquetas con ese nombre. Lo que no veo es el caso que plantea la pregunta, consistente en editar masivamente un término para usar otro: no creo que sirva especialmente a la causa.

Answer (score -1):

Yo entiendo que el uso correcto en Español sería la palabra `vector` o `matriz`.

Definición de vector (RAE): [Link](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bQE7djR)

Definición de matriz (RAE): [Link](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OdYpUcZ)

Desde luego, utilizar la palabra `arreglo` como `array` en términos informáticos, no es adecuado.

Comment: entiendo que es el uso que se le da en tu zona/ambiente laboral. Leyendo las respuestas y comentarios, vamos viendo que cada uno utiliza términos distintos. Y la RAE no define las reglas del español para todo América Latina. ¿No te parece que el punto que planteás como que "*no es adecuado*" quizás sólo aplicaría para el español de España?

Comment: No Pedro, la traducción correcta de array es arreglo. Vector es un arreglo de una dimensión, matriz es un arreglo de múltiples dimensiones. Los términos vector y matriz en informática se toman de la matemática, no de la RAE o algo por el estilo.

Comment: ¿Alguien podría, por favor, indicarme un texto oficial, como seria la RAE,  donde se indique que la palabra "arreglo" significa "matriz"?

Comment: @Mariano, la mayoría de países de América Latina tienen sus propias sedes de la RAE y aportan palabras de uso habitual en dichos países al diccionario Español, que por supuesto son válidas. De 'arreglo' no recoge ningún uso relacionado con el termino inglés *array* utilizado en informática.

Answer (score -1):

Para empezar una reflexión:

> **Mario Galindo Queralt, Doctor Ingeniero especializado en Diseño Estructural.**
>   ¿Debo aprender inglés para aprender un lenguaje de programación?
>   La respuesta simple y franca es: SI.
>   Si quieres programar bien debes aprender inglés.
>   Lo siento pero el que te diga lo contrario te está mintiendo...

Artículo completo en:
[¿Por qué no hay lenguajes de programación en español?](https://es.quora.com/Por-qu%C3%A9-no-hay-lenguajes-de-programaci%C3%B3n-en-espa%C3%B1ol-Debo-aprender-ingl%C3%A9s-para-aprender-un-lenguaje-de-programaci%C3%B3n)

¿Y después de esto?

Según el Cambridge dictionary **Array** significa:

> Un gran grupo de **cosas** o personas, especialmente una que sea atractiva o que cause admiración o que haya sido **posicionada de una manera particular**

O como sinónimo:

> Grupos y colecciones de cosas.

**Arreglo** no leva las palabras *grupo* o *colección* en ninguna de sus acepciones.

El uso de palabras que no encajan en el contexto donde han sido escritas o son moda es un auténtico snobismo. Alguien lo puso de moda y el resto, si ni siquiera cuestionarlo, lo extendió.

No digo que no se pueda utilizar, faltaría más, digo que *arreglo* es una mala traducción o adaptación de una palabra que define perfectamente lo que es. No hay ningún diccionario latino que asocie *arreglo* a lista de cosas o algo que se le parezca.

Se desconoce la etimología y quien o porqué acuñó esta "nueva" palabra.

Además, si todo el mundo sabe que es un **array** y sabe utilizarlo y sin embargo hay tanta controversia con **arreglo**, ¿por qué dicutir tanto por esto?.

Comment: Que no guste una respuesta no significa que no aclare cosas. Puntuar -1 sin argumentar es algo que está fuera de mi etica. He visto que hay gente que utiliza el -1 como recurso a su respuesta en una discusión sobre un tema. **No me gusta lo que dices. Si, es cierto lo que dices pero no me gusta. Toma -1**  A mi no se me ocurre hacer algo así pero claro, yo nací en el 69.

Comment: He sido yo el del -1. Me has pillado conduciendo a casa después del trabajo y por eso he tardado en contestar. Te he votado negativo porque lo que dices no es correcto. Arreglo viene de arreglar que se podría traducir como arrange que significa organizar o poner cosas en orden. No es cuestión de esnobismo.  Al principio los términos se intentaban traducir al idioma propio, y el término arreglo (como menciono en otro comentario)  era bastante común como traducción de array (que también se traducía a veces como vector).

Comment: Antes de nada quiero disculparme si el siguiente texto suena agresivo pero nada más lejos de la realidad. Desgraciadamente las conversaciones escritas no muestran los gestos ni el tono de las palabras. Por favor, léelo como si estuvieses hablando con un hermano o un amigo, pero también imagina cierta intensidad en el debate ;-D

Comment: Obtenido de varias fuentes, incluida http://etimologias.dechile.net para que no piensen que la RAE es dogma.
El verbo arreglar viene del latín con a- (del latín ad-) y reglar, verbo que también viene del latín regulare (dirigir, reglar normativizar), derivado de regula (barra de medir, regla, norma). Comparte raíz indoeuropea “reg-” (mover en línea recta, enderezar). 
Como verás, no hay relación oficial alguna con “arrange”. Puede ser que en tu edificio, barrio o ciudad, la gente utilice arreglo como sustituto de array pero sin duda es una mala traducción que trata de hacerse un hueco.

Comment: Aseverar que mi respuesta es errónea es una falacia puesto que tú dices que: Arreglo viene de arreglar que se podría traducir como arrange que significa organizar o poner cosas en orden.  Mientras que mis palabras son ciertas y documentadas tu argumentación es subjetiva, basada en un “podría” que sale de una opinión personal. No hay ningún diccionario que relacione arreglo con arrange, salvo el diccionario de la calle. Pero claro, si seguimos así podríamos acabar hablando esperanto y yo te podría hacer una llamada desde mi “tino” que es como mi hija pequeña llama al teléfono.

Comment: La traduccion de arrange a arreglo es una de las peorres traducciones que se pueden encontrar en la web  Eres tú quien no está en lo cierto y el que ha puntuado +1 tu comentario debería ser más crítico. La ética de este site (sitio para los puristas) impide la votación desinformada. Votar +1 o -1 implica cierta responsabilidad, buen criterio y argumentación. No se puede votar ni +1 ni -1 si tus argumentos estan basados en un *creo que* o un *podría ser*. En estos casos simplemente, no se vota.

Comment: Etimológicamente estoy de acuerdo. Como comento en [mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4159/83) es algo que debatimos en Spanish.SE y la conclusión lingüística es que _arreglo_ no es una traducción apropiada. Dicho lo cual, en el mundo de la informática para bastante arraigada y contra esto poco puede hacerse pues la lengua es de las que la hablan.

Comment: No termino de entender como es que se ha reabierto una discusion de 2016, pero bueno. Solo quería comentarte @APO69 que en las publicaciones de meta, los votos positivos y negativos indican precisamente si estas a favor o en contra de la opinion expresada en dicha publicación. Meta no es como el sitio principal en el que se debería votar la "calidad" de la publicación. En Meta es mas una "encuesta" sobre si estas a favor o en contra, asi que no debes tomarte ningun voto como nada personal.

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo tu comentario @Pikoh, soy muy nuevo por aquí y me estaba rayando mucho con lo de los -1, como se habrá visto. Gracias otra vez. lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score -1):

[Edición sugerida por tener una palabra en inglés, pero de uso habitual (array)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/700/edici%C3%B3n-sugerida-por-tener-una-palabra-en-ingl%C3%A9s-pero-de-uso-habitual-array)

Esta es la pregunta a la que respondo según aparece el 06/01/2023

La modificación iterativa y continuada de términos del lenguaje traducidos al castellano (español) no es una solución al problema de fondo.
El problema de fondo es *¿debemos traducir las palabras reservadas por el lenguaje de programación a nuestro idioma?*
Quizás sería adecuado generar una nueva pregunta para iniciar un nuevo debate "polémico".
Lo considero innecesario, esta pregunta tiene la antigüedad y el prestigio adquirido al cabo del tiempo. ("solera")
Mantengo el enlace a
[MDN "reserved words"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words).

**La respuesta corta a la pregunta de fondo, es definitivamente, un rotundo "NO"**

---

Justificación:

---

Las palabras reservadas en los diferentes lenguajes de programación no son términos lingüísticos (de diccionario), si no términos que representan un elemento o funcionalidad de dicho lenguaje.
Vayamos a la raíz de la palabra en cuestión "`ARRAY`" en JavaScript.
En JavaScript todo es un `OBJECT` que se suele traducir como "OBJETO".
Existen elementos "PRIMITIVOS" entre los que se encuentra dicho término.
Desglosemos, al menos en parte, dichos elementos.
En la cabecera tenemos dos especificados. `UNDEFINED` y `NULL`.
Esto nos lleva al concepto de `OBJECT`, que representa (hablando en términos matemáticos) al elemento del subconjunto de elementos que poseen un nombre y un valor asociado, es decir, pares de `{KEY, VALUE}`, y debido a ello, un `OBJECT` se dice que es `NULL`, primitivo de `OBJECT`, y por lo tanto su `TYPEOFF` es un `OBJECT`, y se dice que representa al elemento (conjunto) vacío, aunque en realidad representa al ***objeto*** que no contiene elementos.
Por otro lado, al objeto que ha sido declarado y , pero al cual, aún no se le ha asociado ningún valor se le denomina `UNDEFINED`.

Dentro del conjunto de los elementos `OBJECT` tenemos un subconjunto (al que las traducciones del inglés se refieren como "superconjunto", y no entiendo el porqué) de elementos en los que el nombre o clave (`KEY`) es un número **NATURAL** (conjunto de los enteros positivos, *que por cierto, también incluyen al cero como primer elemento, y es la razón real de su uso como primer índice y no de otras razones como se dice por ahí.*), a los que el lenguaje JavaScript denomina **`ARRAY`**.

---

Así pues, como podemos observar, el pretender traducir los términos de un lenguaje informático presenta complejidades innecesarias y es la causa principal de confusiones que conllevan a cometer errores, que en ocasiones son muy difíciles de detectar; y a los principiantes nos provocan ataques de apoplejía.

---

**¿Es ello un motivo para dedicarse a corregir todas las apariciones de los términos traducidos?** Reitero "NO", sería una labor titánica e ímproba. En especial cuando el redactor insiste en utilizar la traducción del término, revirtiendo la corrección. (*es por eso por lo que yo ni lo intento, me provoca tristeza, pero como dice el refranero popular "hacer de tripas ... corazón"*)
A esos esforzados correctores les sugiero dediquen sus esfuerzos a generar nuevas preguntas o respuestas actualizando los códigos a los nuevos estándares, como por ejemplo sustituir las apariciones de `var` con `let` o `const` **sin corregir el Código original** tan solo redactar una actualización de dicho código y enlazarla *linkearla* al sitio original.
Esto generaría que los nuevos programadores adquiriesen buenos hábitos y costumbres, ya que las preguntas / respuestas antiguas suelen estar desfasadas, e inclusive utilizando terminología en desuso o desaconsejada.

---

Comment: Como he obtenido un voto negativo, intentaré cambiar mi respuesta a una justificación más completa y técnica, de porqué en lugar de editar la pregunta/respuesta se debería generar un duplicado, con la corrección necesaria y justificada. Probablemente con previa autorización de los moderadores.